# Plot output not right in Animation in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create an animation of a simple plot:

[image]

First few rows of the data are:

```
   Vehicle.ID Frame.ID    ycoord PrecVehycoord
1          56      529  80.38800      138.1898
2          56      530  82.88762      140.9135
3          56      531  85.38742      143.6725
4          56      532  87.88751      146.4588
5          56      533  90.38760      149.2669
6          56      534  92.88771      152.0930
7          56      535  95.38778      154.9337
8          56      536  97.88776      157.7867
9          56      537 100.38773      160.6493
10         56      538 102.88808      163.5188
..        ...      ...       ...           ...
```

Following is the code I am using to animate it:

```
library(animation)
oopt <- ani.options(interval = 0.1)

FUN <- function() {
  lapply(unique(a$Frame.ID), function(i) {
    print(ggplot(data = subset(a, a$Frame.ID==i)) + 
            ggplot(data=a) +
            geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Frame.ID/10, y = ycoord, color = "Subject Vehicle")) +
            geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Frame.ID/10, y = PrecVehycoord, color = "Lead Vehicle")) +
            labs(x = "Time(sec)", 
                 y = "Distance (ft)") + theme_bw() + 
            ggtitle("Time-Space Diagram") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=32, hjust=0)) +
            theme(axis.title = element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=22),
                  legend.title=element_blank(),
                  legend.text = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
                  axis.text  = element_text(size=16))) 
    
    animation::ani.pause()
          
  })
}

FUN()
```

## Problem

This code creates only 2 points on the plot (one per `geom`) at a time for a given `Frame.ID`. The points for the `Frame.ID`-i do not remain on the plot.

I want the previous points to stay on the plot so that when the last 2 points are created the plot is complete similar to above plot.

Comment: Maybe you want `1:i`?

Comment: @TylerRinker No. Because `i` represents `Frame.ID` which is not in the sequence `1,2,3,...`, rather it starts from 529 as shown in the data in the question.

Comment: What I see is you're subseting by a single index, giving a single row hence your only getting 2 points.  You need to include all the rows prior so 529:i or something that gives you all the previous `i`s as well.